# CUDA-related error in Visual Studio 2012: Unable to create directory, format is not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

While compiling a CUDA code I am getting this error

> C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   5.5.targets(412,9): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "Debug\D:\Matrix Multiplication Example\MatMul\". The given path's
>   format is not supported.
>
> Build Failed

Need some direction in this regard.

Comment: This appears to be a Visual Studio question not related to CUDA. Try cleaning your project: Build -> Clean Solution.

Comment: @JackOLantern It's a bug in the CUDA plugin for VS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid path on windows:

> "Debug\D:\Matrix Multiplication Example\MatMul\".

The drive letter `D:` must appear first in the path.

You'll need to work through the project settings to find out where this is getting set, and revise it.

Comment: I am having the same error. Did someone find solution to it? how to resolve this error? Which project settings to  change. My CUDA Build customization are correct as other projects get successfully built with the same Build Customization.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .pbxproj for absolute source paths.  They're valid in .pbxproj (if usually not a good idea), but they break CUDA's build customization.  It assumes $(IntDir)%(RelativeDir) is valid, hence "Debug\" + "D:\Matrix Multiplication Example\MatMul\".

It's a bug in the CUDA scripts, but it's easy enough to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary workaround to circumvent this issue.

Put all your cuda files (cu, cuh) files in the visual studio project folder and then add them to the project using add existing item option. Then try compiling. It should work.

I think its a windows + visual studio problem.